# css float elements with unequal heights left and up in grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout

I'm wondering how I can accomplish the effect in figure 1.

[image: Float left up]

What I have got so far is

`.box { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 100px;}`

This gives me the result illustrated in figure 2.
(Notice: I'm aware I can accomplish the same with float: left)

My HTML code looks something like this:

```
<span class="box">A<br><br><br><br></span>
<span class="box">B<br></span>
<span class="box">C<br><br><br></span>
<span class="box">D<br><br><br></span>
<span class="box">E<br><br><br><br><br><br></span>
<span class="box">F</span>
<span class="box">G<br><br><br><br></span>
<span class="box">H<br></span>
<span class="box">I<br><br></span>
```

I want every element to be floated to the left as far as possible, but meanwhile floating upwards.

Is it possible to do this with pure css, or will i need some javascript?

**EDIT:**

It is important for me that the entire grid is positioned to the center of the page. That's why I use display:inline-block. The grid should also not be fixed to the page because I want it to reflow when I resize my window.

Comment: Since you are already using jquery jquery masonry might interest you: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: @Chandu: awesome. I'm trying it out now. Could you post this as an answer, so I can accept it if it works out ;)

Comment: Hm, I'm pretty sure this can be achieved with css alone.

Comment: @Christoph could you tell me how?

Comment: Do you always want 3 columns? Can you add more markup?

Comment: well, I just played around a little and it seems, the effect in figure (1) can't be achieved directly only with straingt css.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the popular library [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

> A dynamic layout plugin for jQuery The flip-side of CSS floats

Here is a code [example](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html)...

```
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box'
});
```

Here is the source on [Github](https://github.com/desandro/masonry) and an interview with [David Desandro](http://shoptalkshow.com/episodes/024-with-david-desandro/) on the Shoptalk podcast.

For folks that aren't using jQuery, note that there's also [Vanilla Masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/) which is the framework-free version.

**Tip:** Make sure the parent container has position:relative so all the content is bound to your container.

Comment: @Jules: I added a tip how to make sure the floating elements stay in your container.

Comment: thanks. I accepted Chandu's answer because he was first. Yours is equally good for me though. Too bad I can't accept more than one answer.

Comment: Well while Chandu wrote a one line comment I crafted this answer with a lot more info. My bad ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Since you are already using jquery, jquery masonry might interest you: http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: It works, but not completely what I wanted. I should have mentioned I use display:inline-block because I want to center my grid on the page. Masonry floats everything to the left of my page, and than changes the position of my boxes to absolute. So the boxes aren't aligned to the center.

Comment: Oh, figured it out. I can just center my boxes container with isFitWidth: true and wrapping my boxes in a centered container. It's explained here http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/centered.html

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you only aim to support the most modern browser, the [CSS3 multi-column layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS3_Columns) could help. One problem with this approach is that it will not keep the same order, but you can play with the order in the HTML (or Javascript).

I added a container around your spans called `#container`.

```
#container { 
    -webkit-column-width: 100px; 
    -moz-column-width: 100px; 
    column-width: 100px; 
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/Ft9d2/)

Comment: great, this will be very useful in the future. But for now i'm gonna stick with the jquery solution.

Comment: items will be out of order with a column layout