# Get floats to "float up" to fill space

Tags: css, css-float

Each of the boxes in the screenshot below are styled with "float: left".

How can I make them float to whichever "column" first has a space? (e.g. in the example below, move the Music Nation box where the red arrow shows)

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [css float elements with unequal heights left and up in grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434756/css-float-elements-with-unequal-heights-left-and-up-in-grid)

Answer (score 2):

You can put the columns at the right side styled with `float:right`. This should do the trick, but I really don't know if there is a best practice for that.

You can also put a negative margin-top at the box to pull it up, but in my opnion, it's a bad practice. You should try the first one I said.

**Edit**: I think this will be interesting for you: http://masonry.desandro.com/