# vertically float a div

Tags: html, css

How to make a div to float vertically? If there is empty space above a div then it should go up and fill up the space leaving the empty space at the bottom.

```
 float:left // for floating horizontally
```

I have many div which are floating horizontally with a fixed width but not a fixed height. I want them to be arranged without leaving the empty space.

How can this be done?

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

A div would never leave empty space above itself. It will fill the space and then the document would go on to the bottom.

I guess, there is some sort of `padding` or `margin` there.

You can try to give the divs an absolute position as:

```
div {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
```

This way, div will be placed almost to the top of the page! Overlapping other elements, You can give some value to `top` in such a way that you're giving `margin-top`.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume you're experiencing the following problem: you have some divs with different heights one after another in several rows.  Say, there's a very tall  in the first row, forcing all the divs of the second row to "dive" deeper. I have a strong feeling, that there's no cross-browser pure-css way to improve this look much at the moment. However, you can achieve at least something with

```
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top
```

instead of

```
float:left.
```

It will look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wHTQ2/

if you need something better looking, please, see this question:
[css float elements with unequal heights left and up in grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434756/css-float-elements-with-unequal-heights-left-and-up-in-grid)
I believe it's the same thing that you're looking for. Unfortunately, there's not much you can do with pure css