# Floating divs being pushed down

Tags: css, css-float

I'm so unsure of why this is happening, I'm having a lot of trouble finding a solution, so here it is plain and simple

HTML

```
<div class="thing"></div>
<div id="big" class="thing"></div>
<div class="thing"></div>
<div class="thing"></div>
<div class="thing"></div>
<div id="big" class="thing"></div>
<div class="thing"></div>
```

CSS

```
.thing {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

#big {
    height: 140px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sdmq155g/1/

The blue divs on the bottom shouldn't be pushed down unless there is a big div above them. They should all nestle right up underneath the div above them. But for some reason, all their positions are based off of the bigger divs in the top row, even though they're not all directly below one.

Comment: Looks like you are going for a grid look. Unfortunately, there is no way to create that style without using javascript. You can use masonry to create it. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434756/css-float-elements-with-unequal-heights-left-and-up-in-grid

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful. Is it possible to use masonry javascript when coding a custom tumblr theme?

Comment: yea it is really easy to do. There are tons of things on tumblr that use masonry. Even tumblr's archive uses the system. Here is a link on how to do it http://buildthemes.tumblr.com/ch5/infinite-scroll-and-grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The box model that all browsers implement behaves in exactly the way your jsFiddle demonstrates. The blue divs won't nestle up underneath each other, but in fact they will start on the next line based on the tallest item on the row above.

You could overcome this by placing the divs you'd like to stack in a column, then floating these divs.

Example here:

```css
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
}
.thing {
    background-color: blue;
    border: solid 1px red;
    height: 100px;
}

#big {
    height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
    <div class="thing"></div>
    <div id="big" class="thing"></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div id="big" class="thing"></div>
    <div class="thing"></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="thing"></div>
    <div id="big" class="thing"></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="thing"></div>
    <div id="big" class="thing"></div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="thing"></div>
    <div id="big" class="thing"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess this would work, although I was hoping to have the "things" be added from left to right from a list of divs, the way Pinterest does with their pins.